# websphere jms queue access from remote client

Tags: java, jms, websphere

**Background**
I am php & frontend web developer developing an application in Java using Netbeans to read from a websphere (V8.5 I think) JMS queue and then issue commands to appropriate scripts/servers. This is my first major run in with Java for about 10 years so please bear with me.  My initial test application runs fine on the server that hosts the jms queue but I have been running into one error after another when trying to connect from a remote location (which at the moment happens to be windows but will be linux in the end). I have been battling through both my lack of experience with Java the process of diagnosing jar issues and locating apparently needed jars from websphere and elsewhere but have finally reached a brick wall.  I have seen lots of answers that consist of statements such as "you need the right jar files", but not saying which ones or you need thisone.jar and all the jars that one refers to. I don't know how to find out what jars that should be.  I have read posts that say that the process should work with only some of the jars in my library.  Am completely stuck...

**Error**
The error which I am having no luck in getting through

```
 javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to initialize the ORB [Root
 exception is org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB
 implementation com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB
```

The full rest of message is this

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to initialize the ORB [Root exception is
org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation 
com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]   
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:314)     
javax.naming.NamingException: Failed to initialize the ORB [Root exception is  org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation  
com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No]   
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:384)   
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:113)    
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:428)  
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:144)    
at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)  
at jmstool2.JmsConn.CreateFactCon(JmsConn.java:101)     
at jmstool2.JmsConn.connect(JmsConn.java:56)    
at jmstool2.Jmstool2.main(Jmstool2.java:20) 
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB  vmcid: 0x0  minor code: 0  completed: No  
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl(ORB.java:327)  
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.init(ORB.java:367)     
at com.ibm.ws.orb.GlobalORBFactory.init(GlobalORBFactory.java:85)   
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORBImpl.initializeORB(EJSORBImpl.java:174)     
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:97)     
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSClientORBImpl.<init>(EJSClientORBImpl.java:73)     
at com.ibm.ejs.oa.EJSORB.init(EJSORB.java:386)  
at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.Helpers.getOrb(Helpers.java:305)  ... 8 more 
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: UNKNOWN  
at com.ibm.rmi.util.RepositoryId.createHashString(RepositoryId.java:738)    
at com.ibm.rmi.util.RepositoryId.<clinit>(RepositoryId.java:254)    
at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.CDROutputStream.<clinit>(CDROutputStream.java:1107)     
at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ORB.<init>(ORB.java:281)   at com.ibm.rmi.iiop.ORB.<init>(ORB.java:187)    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB.<init>(ORB.java:576)  
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)    
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)     
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:374)
at org.omg.CORBA.ORB.create_impl(ORB.java:325)  ... 15 more
```

**What I am doing**
I have added the following jars to the library

```
javax.jms-1.1.jar 
com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar 
com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar 
com.ibm.was.sib.client.thin.jms_8.5.0.jar 
com.ibm.was.admin.client_8.5.0.jar 
com.ibm.ws.messagingClient.ja
```

I have also read that the following jars are needed

```
sibc.jms.jar
sibc.jndi.jar
sibc.orb.jar
```

I have located these and added them also, although I have also read that these are not needed if you have the thin client I already have.

and am using JDK1.7

```
context factory: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory 
Provider URL: corbaloc:iiop:192.168.254.202:2809
```

The context is being created. But am unable to make the queue factory connection.  I can create a socket to the ip address and post using a quick test application.

**The Code**
Here is the class file and all the connectiony bits.  It is complete work in progress.

```
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.*;  
import javax.jms.*;
import com.ibm.CORBA.*;
import com.ibm.ws.*; /* 
/**

 * Connection Factory Notes on IBM Websphere
 * 
 * jndi/INConnectionFactory
 * jndi/OUTConnectionFactory 
 * 
 * jndi/INQueue
 * jndi/OUTQueue
 * 
 * jndi/INActivation  
 * jndi/OUTActivation  
 * 
 * websphere server:  192.168.254.202
 * 
 * JMS queued port: 5558  unsecured (MQ)   and 5578 secure
 * JMS Security Port 5557
 * JMS Direct Port: 5559
 * SOAP: 9976
 * //other ports mentioned: 7276 (unsecured) and 7286 (secured)
 * NOTE:  A bootstrap address with no port specification defaults to port 2809
 */
public class JmsConn {
    /*int jmsQueuedPort   = 5558;
    int jmsSecrityPort  = 5557;
    int jmsDirectPort   = 5559;
    int soapPort        = 9976;*/
    int bootstrap       = 2809; //default port
    int bootstrap10     = 2810;
    int unSecPort       = 7276;
    String serverIP     = "192.168.254.202";    
    String scheme       = "corbaloc:iiop:"; //e.g. ws, ldap,iiop, corbaloc:iiop
    String contextFactory   = "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory";
    String queueInName      = "jndi/INQueue";
    String queueOutName     = "jndi/OUTQueue";
    String outFactory       = "jndi/OUTConnectionFactory";
    String inFactory        = "jndi/INConnectionFactory";
    InitialContext jndiContext;
    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory;
    Connection qConn;
    String providerUrl = scheme+serverIP+":"+bootstrap;
    Session qSession;
    Queue q;


    public void connect() {          
        this.CreateContext();
        this.CreateFactCon(this.outFactory);
        this.getQueue(this.queueOutName);

    }

    public void Lookup(String thingToLookup){
        try{
            System.out.println("Attempting to lookup "+thingToLookup);
        }catch(Exception ex){
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not perform lookup of  " + thingToLookup +             
                System.lineSeparator() + ex.toString());
           // System.out.println("Lookup Result: " + this.jndiContext.lookup);
            System.exit(3);
        }

    }


    public void CreateContext(){
        try{
            System.out.println("Attempting to create connection context");
            Hashtable env = new Hashtable(); // [jh] in theory this has been superceeded 
              // and should use HashMap
            env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,this.contextFactory);
            System.out.println("context factory: "+this.contextFactory);
            System.out.println("Provider URL: "+this.providerUrl);
            env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, providerUrl); //+":"+this.jmsDirectPort
            try{
                this.jndiContext = new InitialContext(env);
                //this.jndiContext = new InitialContext();
            }catch(NamingException e){
                System.out.println("ERROR: Could not create JNDI context: " +  
                   System.lineSeparator() + e.toString());
                System.exit(1);
            }

            System.out.println("End of CreateContext.");  

        }catch(Exception exc){
            System.out.println("ERROR in CreateContext: "+exc.toString());
            System.exit(1);

        }
    }

    public void CreateFactCon(String factory){
        try{
            System.out.println("Attmepting to create factory lookup:");
            this.connectionFactory = (ConnectionFactory)this.jndiContext.lookup(factory);


        }catch(NamingException e){
            System.out.println("ERROR: Could not create factory connection:");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(2);
        }
        System.out.println("Lookup successfull:");

        try{
            System.out.println("Attmepting to create connection:");
            this.qConn = this.connectionFactory.createConnection();
            this.qSession = qConn.createSession(false,Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(4);
        }
        System.out.println("Connection successful.");



        System.out.println("End of CreateFactoryConnection.");            
    }


    public void getQueue(String queueName){
        try{
            this.q = (Queue)this.jndiContext.lookup(queueName);
        }catch(Exception e){
             System.out.println("ERROR: Could not get Queue:");
            e.printStackTrace(System.err);
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            System.exit(2);
        }
    }
    }
```

UPDATE
After cutting back the jar files to

> com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar 
>   com.ibm.ws.wjb.thingclient_8.5.0.jar
>   com.ibm.ws.sib.client.thin.jms_8.5.0.jar

the following error is thrown

```
javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No]
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1552)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootContextFromServer(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1042)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getRootJndiContext(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:962)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.getInitialContextInternal(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:614)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContext(WsnInitCtx.java:128)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.getContextIfNull(WsnInitCtx.java:765)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:164)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtx.lookup(WsnInitCtx.java:179)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
    at jmstool2.JmsConn.CreateFactCon(JmsConn.java:104)
    at jmstool2.JmsConn.connect(JmsConn.java:59)
    at jmstool2.Jmstool2.main(Jmstool2.java:20)
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591  completed: No
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1250)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1321)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1146)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.createRequest(ClientDelegate.java:1287)
    at com.ibm.rmi.corba.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1853)
    at com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ClientDelegate.request(ClientDelegate.java:1243)
    at org.omg.CORBA.portable.ObjectImpl._request(ObjectImpl.java:449)
    at com.ibm.WsnBootstrap._WsnNameServiceStub.getProperties(_WsnNameServiceStub.java:38)
    at com.ibm.ws.naming.util.WsnInitCtxFactory.mergeWsnNSProperties(WsnInitCtxFactory.java:1549)
    ... 11 more
Java Result: 2
```

Comment: I have found this, which is actually a close match, but I am not sure as to how this might relate to Netbeans

SRC: http://veithen.github.io/2013/11/11/servicemix-websphere-ejb-thinclient.html

Find On Page: org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.ibm.CORBA.iiop.ORB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this - [Installing and configuring the Thin Client for JMS with WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/tjj_jmsthcli_dev.html?lang=en).

The only jars you should need for now are:

```
com.ibm.ws.orb_8.5.0.jar 
com.ibm.was.sib.client.thin.jms_8.5.0.jar 
com.ibm.ws.ejb.thinclient_8.5.0.jar
```

so please remove all other from your classpath.
And make sure these jars are also in your run classpath, not only during build.

For initial context try the following:

```
Hastable env = new Hastable();
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL,"iiop://localhost:2809");  // if using default ports
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext(env);
```

Comment: Hi Gas - seem you are the answers guy for this subject as you answered my post yesterday.  I have removed the others from my libraries list and tried the change although localhost is not where the JMS queue (the IP address in the code is the server where it is located) so have left that in but just set to use iiop  and not corbaloc:iiop.  The error returned is:

javax.naming.NamingException: Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible  vmcid: 0x4942f000  minor code: 3591

Comment: This sort of system related stuff is annoying as it takes all the time rather than doing the actual "programming bits" which I can usually work out

Comment: I have read that link previously and it is also cursed with the line "Include the appropriate jar file or files in the classpaths for your client application:"

I seem to be doing what is mentioned there, unless I am missing something. Does adding a jar into my Libraries inside my netbeans project effectively add them to the classpath when running, that was my assumption

Comment: By the way I have checked that the websphere security settings 
Admin Console->Security->GlobalSecurity->RMI/IIOP security are set to SSL supported.  In case that is suggested.

Comment: @JonHolland Hi :). Could you add the full stacktrace with the new error. I see it is similar to that you had in other post. Could you just for a test disable SSL in WAS in `Global security > CSIv2 inbound communications > Transport` set to TCP/IP. And restart the server, so we can rule out SSL.

Comment: stacktrace added to main question text (not sure if there is another way).  See my comment above about the SSL in the IIOP settings.  Will check the ones you have mentioned.

Comment: Confirmed that Transport is set to "SSL-Supported", and Client certificate authentiation is "Supported".  I need to check with a few people before I can restart the server.

Comment: Your update is ok. I know, you wrote it is set to `SSL supported`, but could you try `TCP/IP` also?

Comment: Changed to TCP/IP and restarted.  Error remains the same: 
Error getting WsnNameService properties [Root exception is org.omg.CORBA.TRANSIENT: initial and forwarded IOR inaccessible

Comment: @JonHolland I've tested your class on my local machine with both IBM and Oracle JVM, with SSL-Supported setting and I can successfully connect. Please make sure, if you are using remote server, that there is no firewall between these machines. Or try to move your classes to WebSphere machine and see if it will work locally. Check if your WAS is using Java 7 also (the default is 6).

Comment: yes it runs fine locally on the websphere server itself.  I can create a socket connection to the ip address and port 2809 from remotely.  puzzling isnt it. (Sorry cannot copy to chat, not enough rep)

Comment: It uses also other ports in addition to 2809, thats why I'm asking about firewall. You will need to have open following (giving default values): ORB_LISTENER_ADDRESS=9100, SIB_ENDPOINT_ADDRESS=7276, SIB_ENDPOINT_SECURE_ADDRESS=7286.

Comment: The two SIB ports are now opened up and I can connect a socket to them but the error remains the same. I have been reading this [link](http://www.coderanch.com/t/79498/Websphere/JNDI-error) article which talks about webspheres resolution of the ip address verses the server name. I am looking at the serverindex,xml  - the BOOSTRAP_ADDRESS on 2809 for the host uses the server name.  For the 7276 port it uses host="*"   - might this be the problem as I am accessing the server by IP address?

Comment: No, if you are accessing via ip you are fine. Are you using same Java version remotely that was working locally? I'm slowly running out of ideas. You may try to [enable trace](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/ae/rtrb_orbcomp2.html?lang=en) - add this to your client invocation `-trace=ORBRas=all=enabled -tracefile=filename -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.Debug=true -Dcom.ibm.CORBA.CommTrace=true`. Maybe we will find something meaningful in the trace.

Comment: @JonHolland And how about 9100 port, you have that open too? As you didn't mention.

Comment: Yes that was already open.  I think I have sorted it.  Looking at the orbtraces coming back I was getting an unknownHostException - the websphere was return it's own local server name in the transport connection which the remote machine could not match in the DNS.  I have added the lookup into the remote host file and BINGO!

Comment: The very same DNS issue happened in my case. Entry in `hosts` resolved ORB exception.

Comment: Adding the FQDN in your local hosts file locks you to that IP address. If the IP address changes over time, you will also have to update it on your side. The long term solution is to add the domain name to the search parameter in the /etc/resolv.conf file (on Linux) and let the DSN do it's job.

Answer (score 0):

Update the /etc/resolv.conf file (on Linux) and add the domain name to the search parameter, letting the OS attempt to resolve the hostname, adding the domain name, and calling the DNS. If the IP address changes over time, your system will continue to be able to resolve the domain-less-hostname to the proper IP address.

E.G.: for hostname "jmsserver"

```
Content of /etc/resolv.conf:
domain          mydom.com
nameserver      192.168.1.250
search          xyz.com good.com what.ever.ca
```

If jmsserver is on *good.com*, the OS will use the DNS and attempt to resolve jmsserver.*mydom.com*, jmsserver.*xyz.com*, and will succeed on jmsserver.*good.com* to obtain the IP address to route to the destination.