# How to handle Container Managed,Auto Acknowledge, Transaction Not Supported, MDB exception for message redelivery

Tags: websphere, listener, ibm-mq, websphere-7, ejb-2.x

I got a MDB - EJB 2.1, WebSphere 7 version

Container Managed and Auto Acknowledged

Transactions marked as `Not Supported`

Now how do I handle exceptions in a way that the message will be preserved during exception and redelivered later?

I tried to throw runtime exception from the catch block inside my MDB `onMessage` method. But that seems to stop the MDB Listener which is unexpected.

I cannot call `context.setRollBackOnly()` as there is no transaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RuntimeException` should be fine. Check this out [Message-driven beans - transaction support](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cmb_trans.html?lang=en). If your Listener stops, then you have probably `Maximum retries` set to 0. Set it to something higher.