# Websphere Default Message Provider and Spring JMS

Tags: spring, jms, websphere

I am trying to consume messages from WebSphere SIB (default message provider). I did not find many articles related to this topic on the internet. I have tried configuration as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14737021/spring-jms-with-websphere-default-messaging-issue) but i get the below exception:

```
com.ibm.websphere.ms.Wnsinitalcontextfacotry is not of type javax.jms.ConnectionFactory
```

Has anybody integrated JMS with WebShphere Default message provider? If yes, can you please provide sample code?

I would like to know how to configure connection factory and topic.

CURRENT Status is Below:

I was able to configure JMS connection factory and topic but hit below exception

```
The security exception CAUGHT_EXCEPTION_WHILE_CONFIGURING_SSL_CLIENT_SOCKET: JSSL0130E: java.io.IOException: signals that an I/O exception of some sort has occurred.
```

Comment: Please provide full stack trace. Check [this](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21670402) looks very similar.

Answer (score 1):

Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27962143/websphere-jms-queue-access-from-remote-client). It provides steps and piece of plain Java code, how to access WebSphere Default messaging. You should be able to configure your Spring app based on that.